# The value which is not possible for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ is

Tags: sequences-and-series

> a)25
>
> b)36
>
> c)225
>
> d)441

The value becomes $$\left[\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}\right]^2$$
Since all options are perfect squares, I don’t really know what to do with This.

The discrimaint ie. $b^2-4ac>0$ for all options if we solve the quadratic equation for each option.

The right answer is $25$. How do we get that?

Comment: The $n$ must be a positive integer. Check it again

Comment: What have you tried? You could literally have just added the first three cubes to realise the answer is a), since the partial sums will just keep growing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\left[\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}\right]^2=x$$
It is quadratic in $n$.
$$n^2+n-2\sqrt{x}=0$$
The discriminant $$1+4*1*2\sqrt{x}=1+8\sqrt{x}$$ should be a perfect square because $n$ must be whole number.
So, number need not only be a square number. It should satisfy the above condition as well.
$25$ doesn't satisfy it and hence the answer.

Comment: In 1+4*2*√x, what is it equal to, or is there an inequality present. What is the other condition?

Comment: Discriminant $b^2-4ac$ as you mentioned must be a either $0$ or perfect square if the quadratic equation is to have an integer as a solution.

Comment: Yes of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The expression inside the square is a triangular number. Thus we take the square roots of the choices and see which is not a triangular number, and only the square root of (a) is not so: $5$ as compared to $6,15,21$.

Indeed, $36,225,441$ are the sums of the first $3,5,6$ cubes respectively.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$ is always the square *of a triangular number*, and $m$ is a triangular number iff $8m+1$ is a square. It turns out that options **b**,**c**,**d** are fine (they correspond to $n=3,5,6$), but **a** is not since $8\cdot 5+1$ is not a square.